# how to get the integer value of an enum, when i only have the type of the enum

Tags: c#, enums

I think this question needs some code:

```
private TypeValues GetEnumValues(Type enumType, string description)
        {
            TypeValues wtv = new TypeValues();
            wtv.TypeValueDescription = description;
            List<string> values = Enum.GetNames(enumType).ToList();
            foreach (string v in values)
            {
                //how to get the integer value of the enum value 'v' ?????
                wtv.TypeValues.Add(new TypeValue() { Code = v, Description = v });
            }
            return wtv;

        }
```

Call it like this:

```
GetEnumValues(typeof(AanhefType), "some name");
```

In the `GetEnumValues` function i have the values of the enum. So i iterate the values and i want to get the integer value of that enum value also.

So my values are 'red' and 'green', and i also want to get 0 and 1.

When i have the Enum in my function, i can create the enum value from the string and cast it to that enum and then cast it to an int, but in this case, i don't have the enum itself, but only the type of the enum.

I tried passing in the actual enum as a parameter too, but i'm not allowed to pass an enum as a parameter.

So now i'm stuck.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private TypeValues GetEnumValues(Type enumType, string description)
        {
            TypeValues wtv = new TypeValues();
            wtv.TypeValueDescription = description;
            List<string> values = Enum.GetNames(enumType).ToList();
            foreach (string v in values)
            {
                //how to get the integer value of the enum value 'v' ?????

               int value = (int)Enum.Parse(enumType, v);

                wtv.TypeValues.Add(new TypeValue() { Code = v, Description = v });
            }
            return wtv;

        }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

Enum.Parse will take a Type and a String and return a reference to one of the enum values - which can then simply be cast to int.

Comment: this works! weird though, tried some code in the immediate window, and also this one, which did NOT show me the int value: (int)Enum.Parse(enumType, v) shows me 'De Heer' which is the value of the string 'v'. But when running the code, it DOES show me an int. Weird....

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
(int)Enum.Parse(enumType, v)
```

Comment: +1 There is no need to loop through the values yourself, when there is a method that does that already.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class StringEnum
{


    public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
    {
        string output = null;
        Type type = value.GetType();

        FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        StringValue[] attr = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValue), false) as StringValue[];

        if (attr.Length > 0)
        {
            output = attr[0].Value;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

it is method to get the string value.

```
public enum CampaignRequestType { [StringValue("None")] None = 0, [StringValue("Pharmacy Cards")] Pharmacy_Cards = 1,[StringValue("Prospect Campaign")] Prospect_Campaign = 2,[StringValue("Tradeshow/Advertising")] Tradeshow_Advertising = 3 }
```

its a enum...

```
string item = StringEnum.GetStringValue((Enumeration.CampaignRequestType)updateRequestStatus.RequestType_Code);
```

here `(Enumeration.CampaignRequestType)` is my enumeration
 and `updateRequestStatus.RequestType_Code` is data base field int type

i cast *int* value to *enumeration* type

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow !  try use more the editing tool for code so your answer will be more readable.